# Firefox makes text blurry if I make font-size 30vw+. I tried more fonts, and it's same for every

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

Well, title says it all.

Making font-size in firefox bigger than 30vw will make font blurry/pixeleted, as if it was bad quality image.

I tried font-smoothing and text-rendering but nothing worked for me.

I also tried googling hard for this but couldnt find anything usefull.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? And what operating system / device are you on? Is it reproducible on other devices?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. All my devices are Win10 so can't really compare, but will try later on laptop. Here is screenshot: https://paste.pics/b0d79d5fba4506e409c93b1366cfe3aa

Answer (score 1):

Not a real solution but adding this code with solve the blury font:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.01px;
```